# How to get Graphics card information using Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to get some information of Graphics card using Batch. But I don't know a code. I had tried wmic already. But it doesn't have commands to get Graphics card information. How can I get those information.

Here's My example to display on Batch (like GPU-Z)

```
Name: NVIDIA GeForce 210
Memory Size: 512 MB
GPU Clock: 589 MHz
Memory: 400 MHz
Shader: 1402 MHz
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like this .. Try dxdiag to get the log file and parse it

```
---------------  
Display Devices  
---------------  
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 410M  
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA  
          Chip type: GeForce 410M  
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC  
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1055&SUBSYS_908B104D&REV_A1  
     Display Memory: 1241 MB  
   Dedicated Memory: 482 MB  
      Shared Memory: 758 MB  
       Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)  
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor  
      Monitor Model: unknown  
         Monitor Id: LGD02DC  
        Native Mode: 1366 x 768(p) (59.996Hz)  
        Output Type: Internal  
        Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um  
Driver File Version: 8.17.0012.6721 (English)  
     Driver Version: 8.17.12.6721  
        DDI Version: 11  
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.1  
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail  
   Driver Date/Size: 3/29/2011 14:42:52, 12840040 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I want to get information are integer and string for My installer script.

Comment: @NakornLoader you'll have to write your own utility then